# Получение комментариев через AJAX

Tags: ajax, php, html, javascript, mysql

Есть страница с бесконечной прокруткой, похоже на ВК,тоже с новостями. При загрузке страницы, получение постов и комментарий происходит примерно так.

На сервере

```
$posts = fetch(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 30"));
```

В HTML

```
      <section id="posts" class="posts">
            <?foreach($posts as $post):?>
            <?
                $post_id =  $post['id'];
                $comments = fetch(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id_post = '$post_id'"));
            ?>
                           //...Сдесь блоки для постов

                        <?foreach($comments as $comment):?>
                         //...Сдесь блоки для комментов
```

Но проблема в том, когда доходишь до конца ленты и должна случится подзагрузка, то ты получаешь через AJAX данные, но ты же не можешь там вписать запрос к БД для комментов.
Как сделать, что-бы получить еще 3 последних комментария к одному посту на сервере. Серверный файл для запросов через AJAX выглядит так

```
    $posts = fetch(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts JOIN users ON posts.author = users.id ORDER BY posts.time DESC LIMIT 29, 30"));

    foreach( $posts as $mes ){ //Создается массив объектов
         $array[] = array( 'time' => $mes['time'], 'text' => $mes['text'], 'name' =>  $mes['name'], 'surname' => $mes['surname'], 'lname' => $mes['@name']);
    }
    echo json_encode($array);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут всё делается элементарно, отслеживаем правый scrollbar и когда он будет внизу просто подгружаем данные на страницу и Всего то делов.
[Вот пример](http://www.simplecoding.org/javascript-vidzhet-beskonechnaya-zagruzka-tvitov.html)